# Find the most CPU-intensive SQL queries in a PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

The MySQL process as shown below has a very high CPU consumption:

```
 727936 mysql     20   0 1352784 156928  10088 S  35.2  15.6 743:01.05 mysqld                                                                                 
 286340 www-data  20   0  391300  15584  11736 S   0.7   1.6 107:38.77 nginx                                                                                  
 940017 root      20   0  722604  12500   4796 S   0.3   1.2   0:14.52 snapd                                                                                  
1059116 www-data  20   0  265560  69524  36508 S   0.3   6.9   0:27.37 php-fpm7.4                                                                             
1059192 www-data  20   0  270080  72884  35308 S   0.3   7.3   0:25.44 php-fpm7.4
```

How can I find the most CPU-intensive SQL queries in a PHP application?

The PHP application has more than 300 PHP files, many different queries and I can't catch the SQL queries that are taking the longest time to execute.

I have access to the server and the PHP files, I am looking for a solution to analyze the response time of the requests on the PHP or MySQL side.

***EDIT***

I have activated MySQL's logs:

```
2021-02-14T14:38:20.855971Z    89 Query SELECT DISTINCT id AS frame_size_id, io__frame_size.size
                                   FROM io__frame_size
                                   WHERE standard IN("cm", "both")
2021-02-14T14:38:20.856667Z    89 Query SELECT id, io__frame_size.standard, io__frame_size.size, io__frame_size.size_inch
                               FROM io__frame_size
                               WHERE standard IN("inch", "both")
2021-02-14T14:38:20.863195Z    89 Quit  
2021-02-14T14:38:21.073280Z    90 Connect   myproject_prod@localhost on myproject_prod using Socket
2021-02-14T14:38:21.073643Z    90 Query SELECT * FROM ro__website_option
2021-02-14T14:38:21.074050Z    90 Query SELECT *
                               FROM io__topic ORDER BY position
2021-02-14T14:38:21.074371Z    90 Query SELECT * FROM ext__bce_currency_eurorate WHERE id = 1
2021-02-14T14:38:21.076579Z    90 Query SELECT id, page, name, de, en FROM ro__translation WHERE page LIKE "Search" OR page LIKE "Page" OR page LIKE "Global"
2021-02-14T14:38:21.083431Z    90 Query SELECT * 
                               FROM io__photographer_option 
                               WHERE display_name LIKE 'Gras'
2021-02-14T14:38:21.083901Z    90 Query SELECT DISTINCT id FROM io__keyword WHERE 
  fr LIKE "Gras%" OR en LIKE "Gras%" OR es LIKE "Gras%" OR  de LIKE "Gras%" OR it LIKE "Gras%" OR pt LIKE "Gras%" OR none LIKE "Gras%"
2021-02-14T14:38:21.097753Z    90 Query SELECT DISTINCT id FROM io__keyword WHERE 
  fr LIKE "%Gras%" OR en LIKE "%Gras%" OR es LIKE "%Gras%" OR  de LIKE "%Gras%" OR it LIKE "%Gras%" OR pt LIKE "%Gras%" OR none LIKE "%Gras%"
2021-02-14T14:38:21.113418Z    90 Query SELECT DISTINCT io__image.id, io__image.star, io__image.namefile_title, io__image.namefile_photographer, io__image.namefile_version, 
                                               io__image.size_width, io__image.size_height, io__image.markup_large, io__image.markup_medium, io__image.markup_small,
                                               io__photographer_option.folder, io__photographer_option.display_name, io__photographer_option.nameforurl,
                                               io__photographer_option.markup_currency
                               FROM io__image
                               LEFT JOIN io__image_topic_hext ON io__image_topic_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                               LEFT JOIN io__photographer_option ON io__photographer_option.user_id = io__image.user_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__image_keyword_hext ON io__image_keyword_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                               WHERE (io__image.star >= 10)  AND ( (  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%Gras%"))  OR (io__image_keyword_hext.keyword_id IN(244,895,2409,2484,3554,3777,3906)))
                               ORDER BY 
                                 io__image.star DESC, 
                                 io__image.date DESC
                                LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
2021-02-14T14:38:21.177483Z    90 Query SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT io__image.id) AS number
                                    FROM io__image
                                    LEFT JOIN io__image_topic_hext ON io__image_topic_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                                    LEFT JOIN io__photographer_option ON io__photographer_option.user_id = io__image.user_id
                                    LEFT JOIN io__image_keyword_hext ON io__image_keyword_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                                    WHERE (io__image.star >= 10)  AND ( (  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%Gras%"))  OR (io__image_keyword_hext.keyword_id IN(244,895,2409,2484,3554,3777,3906)))
2021-02-14T14:38:21.240547Z    90 Query SELECT DISTINCT frame_size_id, io__frame_size.size
                                   FROM io__frame_infos_hext
                                   LEFT JOIN io__frame_size ON io__frame_infos_hext.frame_size_id = io__frame_size.id
                                   LEFT JOIN io__frame ON io__frame_infos_hext.frame_id = io__frame.id
                                   WHERE io__frame_infos_hext.available = 1 AND io__frame.available = 1
2021-02-14T14:38:21.241830Z    90 Query SELECT DISTINCT io__frame.id, io__frame.folder, io__frame.version, io__frame.color, io__frame.file_show_small, io__frame.file_show_small_bg, io__frame.width_cm, io__frame.position,
                                               io__frame_size.size,
                                               io__frame_material.material_fr, io__frame_material.material_en
                               FROM io__frame
                               LEFT JOIN io__frame_infos_hext ON io__frame.id = io__frame_infos_hext.frame_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__frame_size ON io__frame_size.id = io__frame_infos_hext.frame_size_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__frame_material ON io__frame_material.id = io__frame.material_id
                               WHERE  io__frame.available = 1 AND io__frame_infos_hext.available = 1 ORDER BY io__frame.position ASC
2021-02-14T14:38:21.243363Z    90 Query SELECT io__price_print_photorag.price,
                                      io__frame_size.size
                               FROM io__price_print_photorag
                               RIGHT JOIN io__frame_size ON io__frame_size.id = io__price_print_photorag.frame_size_id
                               WHERE price IS NOT NULL
2021-02-14T14:38:21.244450Z    90 Query SELECT image_id, lang, title
                               FROM io__image_title WHERE image_id IN(1047,1052,614,541,544,1232,1233,1135,542,265,248,245,209,1049,2268,1050,2739,2738,2643,2642,2641,2640,2583,2582,2581,2538,2536,2540,2522,2422)
2021-02-14T14:38:21.245132Z    90 Query SELECT image_id, lang, title_url
                               FROM io__image_title_url
                               WHERE image_id IN(1047,1052,614,541,544,1232,1233,1135,542,265,248,245,209,1049,2268,1050,2739,2738,2643,2642,2641,2640,2583,2582,2581,2538,2536,2540,2522,2422)
2021-02-14T14:38:21.249009Z    90 Quit  
2021-02-14T14:38:22.112055Z    91 Connect   myproject_prod@localhost on myproject_prod using Socket
2021-02-14T14:38:22.115247Z    91 Query SELECT * FROM ro__website_option
2021-02-14T14:38:22.115745Z    91 Query SELECT *
                               FROM io__topic ORDER BY position
2021-02-14T14:38:22.116069Z    91 Query SELECT * FROM ext__bce_currency_eurorate WHERE id = 1
2021-02-14T14:38:22.118380Z    91 Query SELECT id, page, name, en FROM ro__translation WHERE page LIKE "Search" OR page LIKE "Page" OR page LIKE "Global"
2021-02-14T14:38:22.124842Z    91 Query SELECT * 
                               FROM io__photographer_option 
                               WHERE display_name LIKE 'keywords k lumière'
2021-02-14T14:38:22.125287Z    91 Query SELECT DISTINCT id FROM io__keyword WHERE 
  fr LIKE "keywords k lumière%" OR en LIKE "keywords k lumière%" OR es LIKE "keywords k lumière%" OR  de LIKE "keywords k lumière%" OR it LIKE "keywords k lumière%" OR pt LIKE "keywords k lumière%" OR none LIKE "keywords k lumière%"
2021-02-14T14:38:22.138932Z    91 Query SELECT DISTINCT id FROM io__keyword WHERE 
  fr LIKE "%keywords%" OR en LIKE "%keywords%" OR es LIKE "%keywords%" OR  de LIKE "%keywords%" OR it LIKE "%keywords%" OR pt LIKE "%keywords%" OR none LIKE "%keywords%" OR
  fr LIKE "%k%" OR en LIKE "%k%" OR es LIKE "%k%" OR  de LIKE "%k%" OR it LIKE "%k%" OR pt LIKE "%k%" OR none LIKE "%k%" OR
  fr LIKE "%lumière%" OR en LIKE "%lumière%" OR es LIKE "%lumière%" OR  de LIKE "%lumière%" OR it LIKE "%lumière%" OR pt LIKE "%lumière%" OR none LIKE "%lumière%"
2021-02-14T14:38:22.160901Z    91 Query SELECT DISTINCT io__image.id, io__image.star, io__image.namefile_title, io__image.namefile_photographer, io__image.namefile_version, 
                                               io__image.size_width, io__image.size_height, io__image.markup_large, io__image.markup_medium, io__image.markup_small,
                                               io__photographer_option.folder, io__photographer_option.display_name, io__photographer_option.nameforurl,
                                               io__photographer_option.markup_currency
                               FROM io__image
                               LEFT JOIN io__image_topic_hext ON io__image_topic_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                               LEFT JOIN io__photographer_option ON io__photographer_option.user_id = io__image.user_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__image_keyword_hext ON io__image_keyword_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                               WHERE (io__image.star >= 10)  AND ( (  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%keywords%") OR  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%k%") OR  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%lumière%"))  OR (io__image_keyword_hext.keyword_id IN(19,38,47,49,53,64,65,68,72,77,106,111,114,116,126,132,133,135,140,141,145,155,164,166,171,174,175,179,190,191,193,194,212,217,218,224,227,230,231,233,242,253,260,266,267,281,283,285,288,290,292,302,304,305,310,311,325,334,335,342,343,344,349,350,351,353,369,372,386,389,390,391,392,403,405,410,412,417,421,430,436,439,440,441,445,446,457,461,467,469,472,473,483,492,496,502,503,504,505,508,511,512,513,514,526,527,536,537,545,546,551,552,553,566,569,570,577,583,591,598,601,602,603,615,620,621,627,638,640,642,644,645,665,666,677,678,681,687,698,699,703,707,708,709,710,715,716,723,727,728,729,730,736,737,741,745,746,747,749,758,759,766,771,775,778,783,785,792,793,798,801,803,807,809,816,817,820,821,827,829,834,835,838,839,846,856,859,860,864,865,866,877,880,885,887,896,898,904,913,919,925,929,937,941,947,957,1003,1004,1014,1017,1025,1032,1034,1037,1038,1050,1052,1056,1058,1059,1061,1062,1065,1066,1067,1069,1070,1072,1073,1077,1086,1087,1091,1095,1097,1098,1099,1106,1110,1116,1123,1124,1126,1130,1141,1142,1146,1147,1152,1155,1156,1162,1164,1165,1166,1168,1170,1171,1172,1177,1178,1179,1184,1189,1201,1209,1218,1236,1237,1248,1250,1252,1254,1261,1273,1279,1288,1304,1309,1310,1317,1322,1325,1326,1328,1329,1330,1334,1335,1336,1345,1347,1348,1349,1351,1359,1361,1362,1365,1366,1370,1374,1376,1382,1396,1399,1404,1409,1414,1417,1418,1419,1420,1421,1422,1425,1426,1438,1440,1446,1448,1452,1454,1455,1457,1459,1461,1463,1466,1475,1481,1482,1483,1500,1503,1506,1518,1520,1522,1523,1530,1537,1538,1547,1550,1557,1559,1567,1571,1572,1575,1586,1587,1589,1594,1603,1604,1608,1613,1615,1619,1626,1627,1636,1648,1651,1653,1659,1661,1663,1665,1666,1670,1674,1675,1677,1681,1683,1684,1686,1690,1691,1693,1694,1700,1706,1720,1722,1730,1733,1735,1742,1747,1748,1756,1761,1763,1770,1796,1800,1803,1804,1805,1819,1823,1827,1846,1849,1853,1877,1884,1896,1904,1906,1911,1927,1931,1935,1936,1938,1939,1945,1947,1954,1964,1965,1970,1973,1979,1980,1982,1993,1998,2001,2002,2006,2007,2014,2015,2023,2045,2046,2057,2059,2070,2072,2074,2081,2082,2088,2100,2103,2106,2112,2113,2117,2118,2130,2133,2134,2136,2142,2152,2153,2163,2169,2173,2190,2191,2195,2197,2198,2199,2200,2201,2203,2204,2206,2211,2213,2221,2222,2226,2230,2233,2236,2249,2251,2253,2255,2256,2257,2265,2266,2269,2272,2275,2282,2283,2293,2306,2307,2308,2309,2316,2320,2331,2332,2333,2335,2336,2341,2349,2350,2351,2352,2353,2355,2357,2368,2369,2372,2376,2393,2400,2401,2403,2714,2715,2716,2719,2720,2721,2705,2706,2703,2415,2709,2710,2424,2426,2677,2430,2434,2437,2442,2450,2459,2460,2462,2464,2675,2467,2674,2477,2479,2481,2488,2497,2500,2502,2503,2504,2505,2507,2666,2662,2665,2530,2656,2653,2538,2644,2633,2681,2638,2641,2542,2632,2580,2581,2585,2586,2587,2591,2598,2629,2602,2610,2611,2614,2626,2616,2624,2730,2768,2770,2772,2775,2782,2792,2795,2796,2798,2800,2807,2811,2816,2818,2819,2821,2823,2824,2825,2829,2830,2836,2837,2839,2855,2859,2875,2876,2877,2887,2889,2890,2903,2910,2914,2921,2922,2924,2932,2933,2934,2938,2941,2949,2956,2959,2960,2971,2973,2975,2976,2977,2979,2980,2982,2983,2984,2985,2987,2988,2993,2994,2995,2996,3000,3006,3007,3011,3027,3035,3041,3044,3060,3063,3067,3071,3082,3083,3086,3087,3089,3091,3092,3095,3099,3101,3103,3113,3119,3120,3134,3136,3148,3166,3170,3171,3172,3176,3178,3185,3187,3189,3191,3193,3195,3196,3207,3209,3211,3217,3218,3232,3236,3237,3245,3246,3248,3250,3255,3265,3270,3275,3277,3281,3283,3284,3287,3289,3295,3297,3303,3305,3307,3308,3313,3326,3329,3332,3345,3347,3351,3352,3356,3358,3359,3365,3368,3369,3370,3375,3380,3390,3391,3392,3393,3394,3395,3397,3475,3478,3486,3492,3493,3498,3499,3510,3511,3512,3514,3521,3522,3528,3533,3550,3554,3555,3557,3562,3564,3579,3585,3588,3589,3591,3592,3594,3595,3596,3597,3598,3640,3646,3652,3658,3682,3683,3686,3690,3691,3696,3697,3698,3699,3703,3705,3706,3708,3710,3711,3721,3722,3731,3739,3741,3745,3746,3747,3752,3754,3755,3757,3759,3761,3764,3769,3772,3775,3785,3786,3790,3793,3794,3795,3803,3814,3815,3816,3817,3834,3841,3848,3849,3855,3856,3858,3886,3887,3889,3892,3893,3894,3895,3908,3909,3910,3912,3915,3918,3922,3931,3932,3945,3955,3966,3967,3971,3978,3981,3988,3999,4001,4003,4004,4005,4007,4014,4023,4037,4038,4053,4054,4055,4057,4068,4069,4072,4073,4076,4082,4087,4097,4100,4102,4103,4108,4117,4120,4132,4133,4134,4136,4141,4142,4154,4156,4158,4170,4175,4176,4179,4197,4200,4202,4204)))
                               ORDER BY 
                                 io__image.star DESC, 
                                 io__image.date DESC
                                LIMIT 30 OFFSET 660
2021-02-14T14:38:22.268454Z    91 Query SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT io__image.id) AS number
                                    FROM io__image
                                    LEFT JOIN io__image_topic_hext ON io__image_topic_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                                    LEFT JOIN io__photographer_option ON io__photographer_option.user_id = io__image.user_id
                                    LEFT JOIN io__image_keyword_hext ON io__image_keyword_hext.image_id = io__image.id
                                    WHERE (io__image.star >= 10)  AND ( (  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%keywords%") OR  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%k%") OR  (io__photographer_option.display_name LIKE "%lumière%"))  OR (io__image_keyword_hext.keyword_id IN(19,38,47,49,53,64,65,68,72,77,106,111,114,116,126,132,133,135,140,141,145,155,164,166,171,174,175,179,190,191,193,194,212,217,218,224,227,230,231,233,242,253,260,266,267,281,283,285,288,290,292,302,304,305,310,311,325,334,335,342,343,344,349,350,351,353,369,372,386,389,390,391,392,403,405,410,412,417,421,430,436,439,440,441,445,446,457,461,467,469,472,473,483,492,496,502,503,504,505,508,511,512,513,514,526,527,536,537,545,546,551,552,553,566,569,570,577,583,591,598,601,602,603,615,620,621,627,638,640,642,644,645,665,666,677,678,681,687,698,699,703,707,708,709,710,715,716,723,727,728,729,730,736,737,741,745,746,747,749,758,759,766,771,775,778,783,785,792,793,798,801,803,807,809,816,817,820,821,827,829,834,835,838,839,846,856,859,860,864,865,866,877,880,885,887,896,898,904,913,919,925,929,937,941,947,957,1003,1004,1014,1017,1025,1032,1034,1037,1038,1050,1052,1056,1058,1059,1061,1062,1065,1066,1067,1069,1070,1072,1073,1077,1086,1087,1091,1095,1097,1098,1099,1106,1110,1116,1123,1124,1126,1130,1141,1142,1146,1147,1152,1155,1156,1162,1164,1165,1166,1168,1170,1171,1172,1177,1178,1179,1184,1189,1201,1209,1218,1236,1237,1248,1250,1252,1254,1261,1273,1279,1288,1304,1309,1310,1317,1322,1325,1326,1328,1329,1330,1334,1335,1336,1345,1347,1348,1349,1351,1359,1361,1362,1365,1366,1370,1374,1376,1382,1396,1399,1404,1409,1414,1417,1418,1419,1420,1421,1422,1425,1426,1438,1440,1446,1448,1452,1454,1455,1457,1459,1461,1463,1466,1475,1481,1482,1483,1500,1503,1506,1518,1520,1522,1523,1530,1537,1538,1547,1550,1557,1559,1567,1571,1572,1575,1586,1587,1589,1594,1603,1604,1608,1613,1615,1619,1626,1627,1636,1648,1651,1653,1659,1661,1663,1665,1666,1670,1674,1675,1677,1681,1683,1684,1686,1690,1691,1693,1694,1700,1706,1720,1722,1730,1733,1735,1742,1747,1748,1756,1761,1763,1770,1796,1800,1803,1804,1805,1819,1823,1827,1846,1849,1853,1877,1884,1896,1904,1906,1911,1927,1931,1935,1936,1938,1939,1945,1947,1954,1964,1965,1970,1973,1979,1980,1982,1993,1998,2001,2002,2006,2007,2014,2015,2023,2045,2046,2057,2059,2070,2072,2074,2081,2082,2088,2100,2103,2106,2112,2113,2117,2118,2130,2133,2134,2136,2142,2152,2153,2163,2169,2173,2190,2191,2195,2197,2198,2199,2200,2201,2203,2204,2206,2211,2213,2221,2222,2226,2230,2233,2236,2249,2251,2253,2255,2256,2257,2265,2266,2269,2272,2275,2282,2283,2293,2306,2307,2308,2309,2316,2320,2331,2332,2333,2335,2336,2341,2349,2350,2351,2352,2353,2355,2357,2368,2369,2372,2376,2393,2400,2401,2403,2714,2715,2716,2719,2720,2721,2705,2706,2703,2415,2709,2710,2424,2426,2677,2430,2434,2437,2442,2450,2459,2460,2462,2464,2675,2467,2674,2477,2479,2481,2488,2497,2500,2502,2503,2504,2505,2507,2666,2662,2665,2530,2656,2653,2538,2644,2633,2681,2638,2641,2542,2632,2580,2581,2585,2586,2587,2591,2598,2629,2602,2610,2611,2614,2626,2616,2624,2730,2768,2770,2772,2775,2782,2792,2795,2796,2798,2800,2807,2811,2816,2818,2819,2821,2823,2824,2825,2829,2830,2836,2837,2839,2855,2859,2875,2876,2877,2887,2889,2890,2903,2910,2914,2921,2922,2924,2932,2933,2934,2938,2941,2949,2956,2959,2960,2971,2973,2975,2976,2977,2979,2980,2982,2983,2984,2985,2987,2988,2993,2994,2995,2996,3000,3006,3007,3011,3027,3035,3041,3044,3060,3063,3067,3071,3082,3083,3086,3087,3089,3091,3092,3095,3099,3101,3103,3113,3119,3120,3134,3136,3148,3166,3170,3171,3172,3176,3178,3185,3187,3189,3191,3193,3195,3196,3207,3209,3211,3217,3218,3232,3236,3237,3245,3246,3248,3250,3255,3265,3270,3275,3277,3281,3283,3284,3287,3289,3295,3297,3303,3305,3307,3308,3313,3326,3329,3332,3345,3347,3351,3352,3356,3358,3359,3365,3368,3369,3370,3375,3380,3390,3391,3392,3393,3394,3395,3397,3475,3478,3486,3492,3493,3498,3499,3510,3511,3512,3514,3521,3522,3528,3533,3550,3554,3555,3557,3562,3564,3579,3585,3588,3589,3591,3592,3594,3595,3596,3597,3598,3640,3646,3652,3658,3682,3683,3686,3690,3691,3696,3697,3698,3699,3703,3705,3706,3708,3710,3711,3721,3722,3731,3739,3741,3745,3746,3747,3752,3754,3755,3757,3759,3761,3764,3769,3772,3775,3785,3786,3790,3793,3794,3795,3803,3814,3815,3816,3817,3834,3841,3848,3849,3855,3856,3858,3886,3887,3889,3892,3893,3894,3895,3908,3909,3910,3912,3915,3918,3922,3931,3932,3945,3955,3966,3967,3971,3978,3981,3988,3999,4001,4003,4004,4005,4007,4014,4023,4037,4038,4053,4054,4055,4057,4068,4069,4072,4073,4076,4082,4087,4097,4100,4102,4103,4108,4117,4120,4132,4133,4134,4136,4141,4142,4154,4156,4158,4170,4175,4176,4179,4197,4200,4202,4204)))
2021-02-14T14:38:22.354890Z    91 Query SELECT DISTINCT frame_size_id, io__frame_size.size
                                   FROM io__frame_infos_hext
                                   LEFT JOIN io__frame_size ON io__frame_infos_hext.frame_size_id = io__frame_size.id
                                   LEFT JOIN io__frame ON io__frame_infos_hext.frame_id = io__frame.id
                                   WHERE io__frame_infos_hext.available = 1 AND io__frame.available = 1
2021-02-14T14:38:22.356128Z    91 Query SELECT DISTINCT io__frame.id, io__frame.folder, io__frame.version, io__frame.color, io__frame.file_show_small, io__frame.file_show_small_bg, io__frame.width_cm, io__frame.position,
                                               io__frame_size.size,
                                               io__frame_material.material_fr, io__frame_material.material_en
                               FROM io__frame
                               LEFT JOIN io__frame_infos_hext ON io__frame.id = io__frame_infos_hext.frame_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__frame_size ON io__frame_size.id = io__frame_infos_hext.frame_size_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__frame_material ON io__frame_material.id = io__frame.material_id
                               WHERE  io__frame.available = 1 AND io__frame_infos_hext.available = 1 ORDER BY io__frame.position ASC
2021-02-14T14:38:22.357560Z    91 Query SELECT io__price_print_photorag.price,
                                      io__frame_size.size
                               FROM io__price_print_photorag
                               RIGHT JOIN io__frame_size ON io__frame_size.id = io__price_print_photorag.frame_size_id
                               WHERE price IS NOT NULL
2021-02-14T14:38:22.358717Z    91 Query SELECT image_id, lang, title
                               FROM io__image_title WHERE image_id IN(2477,2427,2424,2389,2388,2387,2386,2384,2380,2079,2375,2373,2372,2371,2370,2368,2366,2365,2339,2333,2332,2331,2325,2323,2321,2318,2316,2315,2313,2310)
2021-02-14T14:38:22.359383Z    91 Query SELECT image_id, lang, title_url
                               FROM io__image_title_url
                               WHERE image_id IN(2477,2427,2424,2389,2388,2387,2386,2384,2380,2079,2375,2373,2372,2371,2370,2368,2366,2365,2339,2333,2332,2331,2325,2323,2321,2318,2316,2315,2313,2310)
2021-02-14T14:38:22.363135Z    91 Quit  
2021-02-14T14:38:23.666334Z    92 Connect   myproject_prod@localhost on myproject_prod using Socket
2021-02-14T14:38:23.666721Z    92 Query SELECT * FROM ro__website_option
2021-02-14T14:38:23.667097Z    92 Query SELECT *
                               FROM io__topic ORDER BY position
2021-02-14T14:38:23.667398Z    92 Query SELECT * FROM ext__bce_currency_eurorate WHERE id = 1
2021-02-14T14:38:23.667828Z    92 Query SELECT io__photographer_option.user_id, io__photographer_option.nameforurl, io__photographer_option.nameforurl_redirect301, io__photographer_option.folder, io__photographer_option.photo_profile, 
                                      io__photographer_option.photo_version, io__photographer_option.link_facebook, io__photographer_option.image_watermark, io__photographer_option.display_name, 
                                      io__photographer_option.show_followers_num, io__photographer_option.show_share_icon, io__photographer_option.images_perpage,
                                      io__photographer_option.markup_currency, 
                                      io__photographer_option.maximages_basic, io__photographer_option.maximages_free, io__photographer_option.maximages_pro, io__photographer_option.maximages_premium,

                                      io__photographer_option.pro_website_link, io__photographer_option.pro_theme, io__photographer_option.pro_background, io__photographer_option.pro_textcolor, 
                                      io__photographer_option.pro_desc_background, io__photographer_option.pro_desc_textcolor,

                                      io__photographer_plan.plan, io__photographer_plan.free_month, io__photographer_plan.end, io__photographer_plan.customizer,
                                      io__customizer_option.available AS customizer_available,
                                      io__image_ourcollection_hext.image_id AS image_ourcollection_id,
                                      ro__user.id AS photographer_id, ro__user.firstname, ro__user.lastname, ro__user.email,

                                      ext__stripe_subscription.status AS pro_status
                                      
                               FROM io__photographer_option

                               LEFT JOIN io__photographer_plan ON io__photographer_plan.user_id = io__photographer_option.user_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__image_ourcollection_hext ON io__image_ourcollection_hext.user_id = io__photographer_option.user_id
                               LEFT JOIN ro__user ON ro__user.id = io__photographer_option.user_id
                               LEFT JOIN io__customizer_option ON io__customizer_option.user_id = io__photographer_option.user_id
                               LEFT JOIN ext__stripe_subscription ON ext__stripe_subscription.id = io__photographer_option.pro_subscription_id

                               WHERE io__photographer_option.nameforurl = '_maky_art_' OR io__photographer_option.nameforurl_redirect301 = '_maky_art_' OR io__photographer_option.folder = '_maky_art_'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.670770Z    92 Query SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
                               FROM io__basket_framed
                               WHERE user_id = NULL OR basket_cookie_id = 'fR5e7y7ETed89BSbjPoM'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.671085Z    92 Query SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
                               FROM io__basket_print
                               WHERE user_id = NULL OR basket_cookie_id = 'fR5e7y7ETed89BSbjPoM'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.671336Z    92 Query SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
                               FROM io__basket_aludibond
                               WHERE user_id = NULL OR basket_cookie_id = 'fR5e7y7ETed89BSbjPoM'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.671579Z    92 Query SELECT count(*) AS num FROM io__wishlist_framed
                                       WHERE io__wishlist_framed.cookie_id = 'fR5e7y7ETed89BSbjPoM'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.672012Z    92 Query SELECT count(*) AS num FROM io__wishlist_print
                                       WHERE io__wishlist_print.cookie_id = 'fR5e7y7ETed89BSbjPoM'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.672234Z    92 Query SELECT count(*) AS num FROM io__wishlist_aludibond
                                       WHERE io__wishlist_aludibond.cookie_id = 'fR5e7y7ETed89BSbjPoM'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.672513Z    92 Query SELECT id, page, name, fr, en FROM ro__translation WHERE page LIKE "Customize your photo" OR page LIKE "Page" OR page LIKE "Home" OR page LIKE "Global"
2021-02-14T14:38:23.679068Z    92 Query SELECT lang, description
                               FROM io__photographer_desc
                               WHERE user_id = '246'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.679797Z    92 Query SELECT io__cat.id, io__cat_name.lang, io__cat_name.name
                               FROM io__cat
                               LEFT JOIN io__cat_name ON io__cat_name.cat_id = io__cat.id
                               WHERE io__cat.user_id = '246'
                               ORDER BY position ASC
2021-02-14T14:38:23.680167Z    92 Query SELECT cat_id, lang, name_url
                               FROM io__cat_name_url
                                WHERE cat_id IN (86,87,88)
2021-02-14T14:38:23.680438Z    92 Query SELECT COUNT(id) AS num
                               FROM io__image
                               WHERE user_id = '246'
2021-02-14T14:38:23.680953Z    92 Query SELECT io__image.id, io__image.position, io__image.namefile_title, io__image.namefile_photographer, io__image.namefile_version, 
                                      io__image.markup_small, io__image.markup_medium, io__image.markup_large, 
                                      io__image.print_maxsize, io__image.size_width, io__image.size_height,
                                      io__image_title_url.image_id
                               FROM io__image_title_url
                            LEFT JOIN io__image ON io__image.id = io__image_title_url.image_id
                               WHERE io__image_title_url.user_id = '246' AND io__image_title_url.title_url = 'intrication.1' LIMIT 1
2021-02-14T14:38:23.682171Z    92 Query
```

***EDIT 2***

I have calculated thanks to the logs that we have an average of 20 connections or queries per seconds. So maybe it's normal that MySQL has a very high CPU consumption!

Some queries related to the search system are too long and take up to 0.4 seconds.

One solution would be to use the nginx cache system for the search system.

Comment: A MySQL server trace?

Comment: slow query log...

Comment: perhaps use an Application Performance Monintor?

Comment: It looks like your WordPress instance has a plugin that handles the publishing and sale of photographs.  And, it looks like your slow MySQL queries come from the code in that plugin: they use tables with names like `io__image`, which aren't part of the standard [MySQL database layout](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). If you [edit] your question to tell us the name of the plugin, we may be able to help you.  **Who can certainly help you? The plugin's developer. Ask them.**

Comment: @O.Jones It's not a wordpress website, it has been hand coded from scratched. Running on a digitalocean small webserver at 5$/month.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I must have misread your question about WordPress. Still, if you can speak to the person who coded the database part of the app. Ask them to help you figure the queries you see. And for some suggestions about troubleshooting this sort of thing [please read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info). And pretty much every database running a successful app runs into this kind of problem. Congratulations!

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you but unfornately for now it's the search engines that make so many SQL queries! Perhaps more than 95% of the hits on our platform are due to search engines! I hope that we will soon have as many hits due to customers and users of the site... ;)

Comment: Do you know how to turn on the Slow Query Log and use long_query_time of .2 seconds?  If not, this URL may be of value to you.  https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/08/09/logging-and-analyzing-slow-queries-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you @WilsonHauck very usefull as information. It was already mentioned by Lars. but with no explanation and didn't understand what he was talking about.

Comment: If you would post last 30 lines of your slow query log in a couple days, we would have some clues on how we could help you.  View profile, Network profile for contact information and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.